# i m confuse about this query

Tags: sql

What is the name|type of this query? Like inner join, outer join.

```
SELECT a.tutorial_id, a.tutorial_author, b.tutorial_count
    FROM tutorials_tbl a, tcount_tbl b
    WHERE a.tutorial_author = b.tutorial_author
```

Comment: It's known as `Implicit joins`  [Explicit vs Implicit SQL joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Answer (score 1):

It's an Implicit `INNER JOIN` most commonly found in older code.  It is synonymous with:

```
SELECT a.tutorial_id,
       a.tutorial_author,
       b.tutorial_count
FROM tutorials_tbl a
INNER JOIN tcount_tbl b ON a.tutorial_author = b.tutorial_author
```

which is also synonymous with just using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.tutorial_id,
       a.tutorial_author,
       b.tutorial_count
FROM tutorials_tbl a
JOIN tcount_tbl b ON a.tutorial_author = b.tutorial_author
```